# Error calling HidP_GetButtonCaps routine from C#

Tags: interop, dllimport, hid

I have spent hours and still can't understand why calling the HidP_GetButtonCaps  routine (from hid.dll) fails when using Interop in C#.

I am listing devices and trying to get ButtonCaps and so on. But when calling HidP_GetButtonCaps (or HidP_GetValueCaps) the extern function returns an HIDP_STATUS_INVALID_REPORT_TYPE error. And I just don't get it... the report type parameter in this routine is a enum value, how can it fails ???

Here is some code extract. I won't put everything because it is long. Of course if more details need to be put, I'll add it.

There are comments in the code "//REMARK", here is the remarks content:
- Remark 1 : the hidDevice object parameter comes from another method. I know the content of the "DevicePath", "preparsedData" and "ButtonCaps" fields are correct when checking things in debugging mode.
- Remark 2 : here is where I have the problem. I've tried 3 different ways for the argument: with a HIDP_REPORT_TYPE object, directly with HIDP_REPORT_TYPE.HidP_Input or "0", and it does not make any difference...

Thanks so much for your help.

Structures, constants, enum... :

```
    public enum HIDP_REPORT_TYPE : ushort
    {
        HidP_Input,
        HidP_Output,
        HidP_Feature
    }

    public struct ButtonCapsRange
    {
        public ushort UsageMin;
        public ushort UsageMax;
        public ushort StringMin;
        public ushort StringMax;
        public ushort DesignatorMin;
        public ushort DesignatorMax;
        public ushort DataIndexMin;
        public ushort DataIndexMax;
    }

    public struct ButtonCapsNotRange
    {
        public ushort Usage;
        public ushort Reserved1;
        public ushort StringIndex;
        public ushort Reserved2;
        public ushort DesignatorIndex;
        public ushort Reserved3;
        public ushort DataIndex;
        public ushort Reserved4;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ushort UsagePage;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte ReportID;
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public bool IsAlias;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public ushort BitField;
        [FieldOffset(6)]
        public ushort LinkCollection;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public ushort LinkUsage;
        [FieldOffset(10)]
        public ushort LinkUsagePage;
        [FieldOffset(12)]
        public bool IsRange;
        [FieldOffset(13)]
        public bool IsStringRange;
        [FieldOffset(14)]
        public bool IsDesignatorRange;
        [FieldOffset(15)]
        public bool IsAbsolute;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public uint[] Reserved;
        [FieldOffset(16 + 10 * 4)]
        public ButtonCapsRange Range;
        [FieldOffset(16 + 10 * 4)]
        public ButtonCapsNotRange NotRange;
    }

    public struct HID_DEVICE
    {
        public String DevicePath;
        public IntPtr pHidDevice; // A file handle to the hid device.
        public bool OpenedForRead;
        public bool OpenedForWrite;
        public bool OpenedOverlapped;
        public bool OpenedExclusive;
        public IntPtr Ppd; // The opaque parser info describing this device
        public HIDP_CAPS Caps; // The Capabilities of this hid device.
        public HIDD_ATTRIBUTES Attributes;
        public byte[] pInputReportBuffer;
        public HID_DATA[] InputData; // array of hid data structures
        public ulong InputDataLength; // Num elements in this array.
        public HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[] pInputButtonCaps;
        public HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[] pInputValueCaps;
        public byte[] pOutputReportBuffer;
        public HID_DATA[] pOutputData;
        public ulong OutputDataLength;
        public HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[] pOutputButtonCaps;
        public HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[] pOutputValueCaps;
        public byte[] pFeatureReportBuffer;
        public HID_DATA[] pFeatureData;
        public ulong FeatureDataLength;
        public HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[] pFeatureButtonCaps;
        public HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[] pFeatureValueCaps;
    }
```

external methods:

```
    [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
    static extern int HidP_GetButtonCaps([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] HIDP_REPORT_TYPE ReportType, ref HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[] ButtonCaps, ref ushort ButtonCapsLength, IntPtr PreparsedData);
```

Call of the method:

```
    private static bool FillDeviceInfo(ref HID_DEVICE hidDevice)
    { 
        //REMARK 1

        ulong numValues;
        ushort numCaps;
        HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[] buttonCaps;
        HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[] valueCaps;
        HID_DATA[] data;
        ulong i;
        ushort usage;
        uint dataIdx;

        hidDevice.pInputReportBuffer = new byte[hidDevice.Caps.InputReportByteLength];

        buttonCaps = new HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS[hidDevice.Caps.NumberInputButtonCaps];
        //for(int a=0;a<buttonCaps.Length ;a++)
        //    buttonCaps[a].Reserved = new uint[10];
        hidDevice.pInputButtonCaps = buttonCaps;

        valueCaps = new HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[hidDevice.Caps.NumberInputValueCaps];
        hidDevice.pInputValueCaps = valueCaps;

        numCaps = hidDevice.Caps.NumberInputButtonCaps;

        if (numCaps > 0)
        {
            //REMARK 2
            HIDP_REPORT_TYPE reportType = HIDP_REPORT_TYPE.HidP_Input;
            int val = (HidP_GetButtonCaps(reportType, ref buttonCaps, ref numCaps, hidDevice.Ppd));
            if (HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS != val)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
//other stuff and retur true at end
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK found the problem... stupid mistake as often.

I solved the problem of the "invalid report type" error by removing the ":ushort" in the enum definition. I thought it was a 2 bytes data in C, but it was a 4 bytes data.

Also, there was a problem with working with tables made in managed memory in HidP_GetButtonCaps.

Instead of using a array of HIDP_BUTTON_CAPS (initialized in managed memory) in HidP_GetButtonCaps, I use a IntPtr refering to an unmanaged memory zone.

Comment: Do you got a working c# application reading the state of a gamepad? I'm searching like crazy for an alternative to DirectInput to accomplish this and this thread is the closer I got to find a solution. It's necessary to include this "hid.dll" together with the files of the application? Or is it a windows standard dll?

Comment: Hi, you can just make a reference to the dll. For instance : [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
static extern void HidD_GetHidGuid(ref Guid guid);

I don't have a working applicaiton reading the state of a gamepad, my application reads raw touch screen input data. I can share it to you if it helps.

Comment: Note that if you are going to use C# Marshalling you need to comment out the int[] Reserved, which is no loss since the explicit layout still skips that space.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same kind of exception. I think there's a problem in the CLR trying to automatically marshall data to a struct with a union. Maybe. I wrote my own unpacking method and that seems to have fixed the problem.

```cs
public static HidpButtonCaps FromByteArray(byte[] bytes, int offset)
{
    var hbc = new HidpButtonCaps()
    {
        UsagePage = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset+1] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset])),
        ReportID = bytes[offset + 2] > 0 ? true : false,
        IsAlias = bytes[offset + 3] > 0 ? true : false,
        BitField = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 5] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 4])),
        LinkCollection = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 7] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 6])),
        LinkUsage = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 9] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 8])),
        IsRange = bytes[offset + 10] > 0 ? true : false,
        IsStringRange = bytes[offset + 11] > 0 ? true : false,
        IsDesignatorRange = bytes[offset + 12] > 0 ? true : false,
        IsAbsolute = bytes[offset + 13] > 0 ? true : false,
        // skip reserved
        Range = new HidpButtonCapsRange()
        {
            UsageMin = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 57] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 56])),
            UsageMax = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 59] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 58])),
            StringMin = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 61] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 61])),
            StringMax = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 63] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 62])),
            DesignatorMin = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 65] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 64])),
            DesignatorMax = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 67] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 66])),
            DataIndexMin = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 69] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 68])),
            DataIndexMax = (ushort)(((ushort)bytes[offset + 71] << 8) | (ushort)(bytes[offset + 70])),
        }
    };

    return hbc;
}
```

I use it like this

```cs
dwSize = hidpcaps.NumberInputButtonCaps;
var bytelength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(HidpButtonCaps)) * (int)dwSize;
HidpButtonCaps[] buttonCaps = new HidpButtonCaps[(int)dwSize];
var pbuttoncaps = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytelength);
hidpstatus = (HidpStatus)HidP_GetButtonCaps(HidpReportType.HidP_Input, pbuttoncaps, ref dwSize, pPreparsedData);
if (hidpstatus != HidpStatus.HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    throw new Win32Exception($"HidP_GetButtonCaps: {hidpstatus.ToString()}");
}

var buttonCapBytes = new byte[bytelength];
Marshal.Copy(pbuttoncaps, buttonCapBytes, 0, bytelength);
for (int i=0; i<(int)hidpcaps.NumberInputButtonCaps; i++)
{
    buttonCaps[i] = HidpButtonCaps.FromByteArray(buttonCapBytes, i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(HidpButtonCaps)));
}
```